# Django while loop

Tags: django, while-loop, django-templates

I wonder if there's any way to do a while loop in django (I think that's what I'm after)?

What I'm trying to do is a nestled ul/li list.

The list is generated by a for loop in a for loop. But since some elements in the second for loop has more child's I want to iterate or them to and so on until all child nodes are iterated out. Only way I found so far is to have another for loop. But this seems not to generic and quite repetitive. And I need to know how many "levels" of child's there are.

This is what it look's like now:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>
            {{ item.name }}
            {% if item.childs %}
                <ul>
                    {% for child in item.childs %}
                        <li>{{ child.name }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                 </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or is there a smarter way to send the data to the template?
Can one do this with some kind of for/while loop?

..fredrik

Comment: I don't see how a `while` would change your situation. Your template seems fine IMO.

Comment: From a purely grammatical point, 'children' would be a better term than 'childs' ;-)

Comment: @voyager: Well in the second for loop each child may also contain child's. And since I don't know how many levels of child's there are (Data is user generated) I wan't to display all data including all child's child's. But as you say while probably isn't the solution:

@Jon Cage: Good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the list into an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), then include it in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [recursion](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/22/recursion-in-django-templates/) could solve your problem if you want to delve down into an 'unknown' depth of child elements? There are [quite a few posts on this out on t'internet](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=recursive+templates+in+django&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) if you search...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think about: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#unordered-list ?